# How to update the one of the value in MAP

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a map object `testMap` declared as `HashMap<String, Test>`.

Test is a simple class which contains references to an `Object` and to two `String` values.

ie,

```
public class Test {

  private String name;
  private String id;
  private Object val;


public Test(Object val,String name.String id){
  this.val =val;
  this.id=id;
  this.name = name;
}
```

I want to update the "name" only in the Hash map "testMap." How can I do this?

Comment: By "name" do you mean the String key by which Test instances are stored in testMap?  ie - if I did `testMap.put("myKey", new Test(o,"str1","str2");`, are you saying that you want to change the `"myKey"` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the visibility of your `name` property to `public` or add a setter to it:

```
public class Test {

  private String name;
  private String id;
  private Object val;


public Test(Object val,String name, String id){
  this.val =val;
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
}
```

Then, to change your name, you need to

```
Test test = testMap.get("key");
if (test != null) {
   test.setName("new name");
}
```

If you want to update the Map key also, then you need

```
Test test = testMap.remove("oldKey");
if (test != null) {
   test.setName("newKey");
   test.put("newKey", test);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Test test = testMap.get("key");
if (test != null) {
   test.name = "new name";
}
```

Comment: Also, for this to work, you should make the `name` member of `Test` class `public` instead of `private`.

Comment: Additional remark: it will change the instance of Test, thus any other reference will see the new value too.

Answer (score 0):

```
Test test = testMap.remove("name");
if(test != null)
   test.put("newname",test);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with the current implementation of `Test` you have, since the name is a private field. You can make it public or add getter/setter methods to the `Test` class (currently the `Test` class seems to be completely useless unless you haven't missed some code).

After that, you can either replace the desired instance of `Test` with a new one with necessary fields, or update the name. Code:

```
public class Test {
  public String name;
  public String id;
  public Object val;

  public Test(Object val,String name.String id){
    this.val =val;
    this.id=id;
    this.name = name;
  }
}

Map<String, Test> testMap = new HashMap<String, Test();
...
Test test = testMap.get(key);
test.name = newName;
testMap.put(key, test);

// or 
Test test2 = testMap.get(key);
testMap.put(key, new Test(test2.val, newName, test2.id));
```